# Fetching correct node using css selector in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For the link,

> http://www.jabong.com/Adidas-Base-Mid-Dd-Blue-Round-Neck-T-Shirt-2733238.html

...I need to get the product fabric detail, **"Polyster"**. But I get **"Fabric"** as output. Below is the part of code.

```
soup.find_all("span", {"class":"product-info-left"})[0].text
```

Answer (score 1):

Find you node `next_sibling`.

```
soup.find_all("span", {"class":"product-info-left"})[0].next_sibling.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.next` or `.next_sibling` here :

```
>>> soup.find_all("span", {"class":"product-info-left"})[0].next.next.text
'Polyester'
>>> soup.find_all("span", {"class":"product-info-left"})[0].next_sibling.text
'Polyester'
```

Answer (score 0):

The info you need is in the `li` tag which is under the `ul` tag, you should find the `ul` first, then you can get all the text in the `li` tag using `stripped_strings`

```
In [47]: r = requests.get('http://www.jabong.com/Adidas-Base-Mid-Dd-Blue-Round-Neck-T-Shirt-2733238.html')

In [48]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

In [49]: ul = soup.find('ul', class_="prod-main-wrapper")

In [50]: for li in ul.find_all('li'):
    ...:     print(list(li.stripped_strings))
    ...:     
['Fabric', 'Polyester']
['Sleeves', 'Half Sleeves']
['Neck', 'Round Neck']
['Fit', 'Regular']
['Color', 'Blue']
['Style', 'Solid']
['SKU', 'AD004MA61NGOINDFAS']
['Model Stats', 'This model has height 6\'0",Chest 38",Waist 34"and is Wearing Size M.']
['Authorization', 'Adidas authorized online sales partner.', 'View Certificate']
```

If you only want the first row, you can use `find()`, it will return the fists element in the `find_all()`:

```
In [51]: text = ul.find('li').stripped_strings  
In [52]: print(list(text))
['Fabric', 'Polyester']
```